# Sorting Words in .txt for excel

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to create a quick .bat to sort some data from cards quickly. But I'm wording if its possible to take the data I'm collecting, and have it sorted in excel automatically. If I could have the data separated by commas, it would be simply to convert it to a csv and be done. but the results.txt file sorts it like this:

```
FN: EXAMPLE A
FN: EXAMPLE B
TITLE: EXAM A
TITLE: EXAM B
ORG: EX A
ORG: EX A
```

and I want it to look more like

```
FN: Example A, Example B
Title: EXAM A, EXAM B
ORG: EX A, EX B
```

Any tips for this?

```
@Echo off
cd /d %~dp0
copy/B *.vcf all_in_one.vcf
copy/B all_in_one.vcf master_list.txt
(
    findstr /C:"FN:" master_list.txt 
    findstr /C:"TITLE:" master_list.txt
    findstr /C:"ORG:" master_list.txt
    findstr /C:"EMAIL;" master_list.txt
    findstr /C:"TEL;TYPE=WORK:" master_list.txt
)>> results.txt
pause
```

Edit:
Is there a way to transpose the data?

such as:

```
FN:                      Title:                    Org:
Example A               Exam A                     Ex A
Example B               Exam B                     Ex B
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FN: Example A, Example B`? I can imagine `FN:, Example A, Example B` fits your needs better.

```
@echo off
setlocal 
(for %%z in ("FN:" "TITLE:" "ORG:" "EMAIL;" "TEL;TYPE=WORK:") do (
  <nul set /p ".=%%~z"
  for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=:" %%a in ('type "master_list.txt"^|findstr /bc:"%%~z"') do (
    <nul set /p ".=,%%b"
  )
  echo/
))>results.csv
```

Pseudo-code:

```
For each of your search-terms
  write the term without linefeed
  for each match
    find the data and write <comma><matched data>, again without linefeed
  next match
  finish the line
next term
```

Result with your example input:

```
FN:, EXAMPLE A, EXAMPLE B
TITLE:, EXAM A, EXAM B
ORG:, EX A, EX A
EMAIL;
TEL;TYPE=WORK:
```

or as it would look like in EXCEL:

```
FN:             EXAMPLE A    EXAMPLE B
TITLE:          EXAM A       EXAM B
ORG:            EX A         EX A
EMAIL;
TEL;TYPE=WORK:
```

Comment: Thank you! I'd hate to impose again, but I made an edit. Could you point me in the right direction? Again, thank you so much! I really appreciate the help!

Comment: Not so straightforward with batch Although possible, a [PowerShell solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46351397/transposing-a-csv-file-using-powershell) might be more reliable.